# Need help to set up Yuima Package for estimating parameters SDE in R

Tags: r, stochastic-processes, optimization

I am replicating a paper's result and here is what I want to estimate:

dx = $A(x,z;\theta)dt + \sqrt D(x,z;\theta)dW$,

where x is the input value from data, z is a constant from data corresponding to each x, $\theta$ is parameters to be estimated, and

$A(x,z;\theta) = 2\theta_{1}*cosh(theta_{2}+x\theta_{3}+\theta_{4}z)(tanh(\theta_{2}+x\theta_{3}+\theta_{4}z)- x)$

$D(x,z;\theta) = \theta_{1}cosh(\theta_{2}+x\theta_{3})(1-xtanh(\theta_{2}+x\theta_{3}))/33)$.

The paper use quasi maximum likelihood (Bollerslev and Wooldridge,1992) and assume:

$E(x_{t+1}|x_{t}) = x_{t} + A(x,z;\theta)\Delta t$;

$Var(x_{t+1}|x_{t}) = D(x,z;\theta)\Delta t$

The main problem is how to add the exogenous variable z into the SDE. I am able to estimate $\theta$ without Z by yuima package:

```
ymodel = setModel(drift = "(2*theta1*cosh(theta2+x*theta3)*(tanh(theta2+x*theta3)-x))",
              diffusion ="(sqrt(2*theta1*cosh(theta2+x*theta3)*(1-x*tanh(theta2+x*theta3))/33))",
              xinit=Data$DI_SP[1])
yuima = setYuima(model = ymodel,data=setData(SDE_Data))
set.seed(123)
QML = qmle(yuima, start= list(theta1=0.1,theta2=0.1,theta3=0.1),
       method = "L-BFGS-B")
summary(QML)
```

And this is part of the data

Time     x           z

1 0.569 -0.15561570

2 0.395  0.34615385

3 0.489  0.03611111

4 0.360 -0.13749521

5 0.155 -0.23845471

6 0.123 -0.03032070

I also try to use [SDE Toolbox](http://sdetoolbox.sourceforge.net/) in Matlab, but I am not able to adjust the functions to make them work. I am also not able to find the paper's authors codes in their sites.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?